# Break chaining methods using sync package

Tags: go, error-handling

Last time I found out I didn't have to check if variable is `nil` to make singleton service but I can use `sync.Once` to achieve the same result, example below:

```golang
// instead of
var instance Instance
func NewInstance() {
    if instance == nil {
        instance = Instance{}
    }
    return instance
}

// can do this
var (
    once sync.Once
    instance Instance
)
func NewInstance() {
    once.Do(func() {
        instance = Instance{}
    })
    return instance
}
```

My question is:
**Can I use `sync` package to break chaining rules and return error?**

Desired result:

```golang
var (
    breakChain sync.SomethingToBreakChain
    err error
)

type s struct {}

func (s *s) F1() s {
    err = service1.DoSomething()
    // sync do something
    return s
}
func (s *s) F2() s {
    err = service2.DoSomething()
    // sync do something
    return s
}
func (s *s) F3() s {
    err = service3.DoSomething()
    // sync do something
    return s
}
func (s *s) GetError() {
    return err
}

func New() {
    s := s{}
    s.F1(). // if error save to `err` variable and break chain here prevent `F2` and `F3` to execute
      F2(). // if error save to `err` variable and break chain here prevent `F3`  to execute
      F3() // if error save to `err` to return
    err := s.GetError()
    // do something with `err`
}
```

Comment: The `sync` package is for synchronizing concurrent code. Method chaining is sequential by definition. You could simply save `err` into the struct `s` and check it at the beginning of each `Fx` method. However what's the actual benefit of method chaining in this case instead of error handling with `if err != nil`?

Comment: Sorry - I'm not really clear what your issue is. I am assuming that by `err = service1.DoSomething()` you mean `s.err = service1.DoSomething()`; your other functions could just check `s.err` before proceeding. Alternatively you could change `func (s *s) F1() s` to `func (s *s) F1() (s, error)` and handle the errors in `New`. For all options you may need a `sync.Mutex` to limit simultaneous access.

Comment: @blackgreen thanks for your comment. Answering your question I was curious if it's possible, and actual benefit may be less `if err != nil` code.

Comment: my advice is to not hack the `sync` package and just handle errors in the usual way. the future you and/or your colleagues will thank you for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to implement a chain like that, you might consider saving the error in the receiver itself and checking in every action:

```
type s struct {
  e error
}

func (s *s) F1() *s {
  if s.e!=nil {
    return s
  }
  // Do things
  if err:=doThings(); err!=nil {
     s.e=err
  }
  return s
}
...
```

Otherwise, there are no mechanisms to prevent calling other methods in the chain.